# CGRect sublayer background didn't centered XAMARIN.IOS

Tags: layout, xamarin.ios, cgrect

I'm trying to use the CGRect class to create a sublayer for a Stack View object, the intention is to create a colored background with rounded edges to make it more pleasing to the eye. As in the picture:

[image]

But as you can see both the green and blue boxes are not centered with the stack views, while the stack views in the xamarin layout are centered, I create the rectangles as follows:

```
        var bg = new UIView();
        var AStack = new UIView();
        var MStack = new UIView();
        var SubInfoStack = new UIView();
        var GreenColor = UIColor.FromRGB(80, 220, 100);
        var SubColor = UIColor.FromRGB(123, 168, 202);

        //CGrect funziona attorno all'oggetto
        bg.Frame = new CGRect(-5, -10, View.Bounds.Width-30, 100);//stackPlico.Bounds;

        //Nel caso ci fossero vincoli a livello orizonatale devi tenerne conto sia nella coordinata di origine (x) che in quella di lunghezza anchessa (x)
        AStack.Frame = new CGRect(15,-30, AltezzaStack.Bounds.Width-15, AltezzaStack.Bounds.Height+60);
        MStack.Frame = new CGRect(MassaStack.CoordinateSpace.Bounds.X + 10, -30, MassaStack.Bounds.Width-10, MassaStack.Bounds.Height+60);
        SubInfoStack.Frame = new CGRect(StackVerticalSubMisure.Layer.Bounds.Left, StackVerticalSubMisure.Layer.Bounds.Top-20, StackVerticalSubMisure.Layer.Bounds.Right+20, StackVerticalSubMisure.Layer.Bounds.Height+40);

        //Coloro i layer
        bg.BackgroundColor = UIColor.TertiarySystemGroupedBackgroundColor;
        AStack.BackgroundColor = GreenColor;
        MStack.BackgroundColor = GreenColor;
        SubInfoStack.BackgroundColor = SubColor; 


        //Coloro i testi
        AltezzaLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        MassaLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        VitaL.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        BracciaL.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        PolpacciL.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        QuadricipitiL.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        ToraceL.TextColor = UIColor.White;

        //Arrotondo i layer
        bg.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
        AStack.Layer.CornerRadius = 50;
        MStack.Layer.CornerRadius = 50;
        SubInfoStack.Layer.CornerRadius = 50;

        //Gli aggiungo agli oggetti di layout
        stackPlico.InsertSubview(bg, 0);
        AltezzaStack.InsertSubview(AStack, 0);
        MassaStack.InsertSubview(MStack, 0);
        StackVerticalSubMisure.InsertSubview(SubInfoStack, 0);
```

I've tried with all the methods I could know to get the exact coordinates and the length of the stack in question to build them around the layer with the background but nothing, when I can center it for one device (iPhone XR) for another (iPhone 8) the frame moves and does not stay centered in the viewcontroller.

Comment: Have you tried using AutoLayaut?

Comment: No, how i do it? with the auto layout that I should give for the creation of the layer, I mean coordinates of origin and dimension.

Comment: Here is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/programmatic-layout-constraints. Using this approach you would have all views be sized and positioned relative to each other, so you won’t deal with coordinates and CGRect’s. And your views would be displayed consistently on all devices.